# mutt sort by score and date

Tags: sorting, multiple-columns, mutt, spool

I'd like to have messages in the mutt spool sorted by reverse-score and if the score is the same then by reverse-date. Is it possible? If I set sort=reverse-score then the secondary sort seems to be only "date".

Answer (score 1):

In your .muttrc

```
set sort = reverse-date
```